# Differences in an array based on groups defined by another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, python-itertools

I have two arrays of the same size. One, call it `A`, contains a series of repeated numbers; the other, `B` contains random numbers.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,3,3])
B = np.array([1,2,3,6,5,4,7,8,9,10,11])
```

I need to find the differences in `B` between the two extremes defined by the groups in `A`. More specifically, I need an output `C` such as

```
C = [2, -2, 2, 1]
```

where each term is the difference 3 - 1, 4 - 6, 9 - 7, and 11 - 10, i.e., the difference between the extremes in `B` identified by the groups of repeated numbers in `A`.

I tried to play around with `itertools.groupby` to isolate the groups in the first array, but it is not clear to me how to exploit the indexing to operate the differences in the second.

Comment: Does each group have a unique value or something like this `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`  is possible?

Comment: Yes, something like your example would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: C is now sorted the same way as in the question

```py
C = []
_, idx = np.unique(A, return_index=True)
for i in A[np.sort(idx)]:
    bs = B[A==i]
    C.append(bs[-1] - bs[0])

print(C) // [2, -2, 2, 1]
```

`np.unique` returns, for each unique value in A, the index of the first appearance of it.

`i in A[np.sort(idx)]` iterates over the unique values in the order of the indexes.

`B[A==i]` extracts the values from B at the same indexes as those values in A.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved using `pandas`' `groupby`:

```
A = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,3,3])
B = np.array([1,2,3,6,5,4,7,8,9,10,11])

import pandas as pd
pd.Series(B).groupby(A, sort=False).agg(lambda g: g.iloc[-1]-g.iloc[0]).to_numpy()
```

output: `array([ 2,  -2, 2,  1])`

using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

[(x:=list(g))[-1][1]-x[0][1] for k, g in groupby(zip(A,B), lambda x: x[0])]
```

output: `[2, -2, 2, 1]`

*NB. Note that the two solutions will behave differently if there are different non-consecutive groups*

Comment: Thank you, this is a great starting point, but—if you notice—the output is not the one desired. I think that ```groupby``` is ordering the groups, while I want them to remain in the order given by the vector ```A```.

Comment: @FDP yes, I fixed that (pandas `groupby` sorts the groups by default)

Comment: Instead of lambda you could use `out = _.agg(['first', 'last']); out['last'] - out['first']` I guess this should be faster than lambda as far as I know.